# How can I create a quadratic equation that flips the parabola, starting at a certain arbitrary point near the vertex?

Tags: graphing-functions, quadratics, conic-sections

Given an arbitrary quadratic polynomial $$ax^2+bx+c$$and a corresponding graph
[image]

where gray lines are axis, black is the parabola, red is an arbitrary line near the vertex,

How would you go about creating an equation for the left-side of the parabola to flip vertically?

That is, I am seeking to create a new quadratic equation, one that will describe the green parabola, where green parabola joins the black on at the intersection point with the red line.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you're looking for sounds like a parametric approach. If you write your equation in the form $a(x-b)^2+c$, then the minimum/maximum occurs at $x=b$. So if you want to create your flipped equation, just do something like $g(x)=a(x-b)^2+c$ for $x\geq b$ and $g(x)=-a(x-b)^2+c$ for $x<$b.

Note that there won't be a single quadratic equation to describe the full curve (on both sides). A simple proof of this fact is that if $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, then $f''(x)=2a$, meaning that the second derivative is constant, and hence never changes sign. Whereas in what you desire, the second derivative would necessarily be negative in the left-half, and positive in the right-half.